# Open fullscreen apps to left of Desktop 1 space

Tags: macos, high-sierra, spaces

In Settings -> Mission Control, you have the option to open a new space to the far right or to the right of the current space via the "Automatically rearrange Spaces based on most recent use" checkbox.

What is a way, perhaps through a terminal command or otherwise, to have new spaces open to the left of Desktop 1 (primary space)?

Answer (score 2):

Up to the current macOS (10.14.2), there is no way to change the default position of full-screen application.

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! Please have a look at the [faq] to understand how the site works and how it differs from the usual forum-style sites, and read https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer which gives some insights into how answers should be written.